# Retrieve data with different datatype

Tags: mysql

I am storing data in my table with char datatype but there are date values also.
The table has only 3 columns 
Name Field Content
The problem comes when i try to retrive dates from the data and have them in ascending or descending order since mysql treats them as strings instead of dates the output isnt quite correct.
Is there anyway i could retrieve the dates telling mysql to treat them as dates and not strings?

Comment: Try using date() surrounded by the column with char datatype so that it treates like a date

Comment: DATE() ignores a timestamp on a datetime field. if it is a string stored in the database then DATE() wont solve the problem. you will have to convert the string to a date http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html --- to treat it as a date...

Comment: the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format and when i try to surround it with date() it gives null as result

Comment: thats probably because it is not a datetime datatype in the database.. its a string.. use the STR_TO_DATE() function to convert it to a date --- look at the link i sent

Comment: of course! i just made it an answer so you can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats probably because it is not a datetime datatype in the database.. its a string.. use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function to convert it to a date.